# Required Content Delivery setup per target

Tags: web8

From the Web 8 documentation it is a bit hard to distill what CD setup is required in the scenario of multiple targets, i.e. Preview/Live.

If I understand correctly per target I would create a Discovery Service database and Broker database (and for XPM a Session Preview database), and the corresponding Discovery Service, Deployer Service and Content Service.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each target purpose Preview and Live is considered a separate Cd Environment. Each of the target would need its own set of services ie. deployer service, content service, discovery service and databases. Any discovery service needs it own db. So for your preview you will need discovrery, broker and session preview db. For live only the discovery and broker db.